# Displaying last string characters

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Could please help to do the below task.

I want to display the string which is coming after last '.' dot opeartor

```
   column1
   ------------
   '123.123|345.5678'
   '2345.897.546|67.967'
```

### o/p

```
    568
    967
```

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: You haven't said what DB or coding language you are using!

Comment: We are using PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 0):

I believe van be done in plenty of ways. First to pop up:

```
t=# select reverse(split_part(reverse('aaa1.bbb2.ccc3'),'.',1));
 reverse
---------
 ccc3
(1 row)
```

Comment: sure. if this answer is acceptable please dont forget to accept it